# Function call not being recognized

Tags: c++

I am writing a magic eight ball program for an assignment. All of my function calls work except for one. I keep getting an error that says there is no matching function to call. A copy of the prototype was used to make the call so I know it isn't a typo. I cannot figure out why as it seems to be set up correctly to me.

main.cpp:

```
int main() {

    const int MAXSIZE = 100;
    int size;
    string responses[MAXSIZE];
    string categories[MAXSIZE];
    srand(time(0));

    start:
    cout << "A. Read responses/categories from file" << endl;
    cout << "B. Play Magic Eight Ball" << endl;
    cout << "C. Sort by responses" << endl;
    cout << "D. Sort by categories" << endl;
    cout << "E. Write responses/categories to a file" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    switch (input) {
        case ('A'):
        case ('a'):

            readResponses(infile, responses, categories , MAXSIZE, size);
            break;
    ...
```

functions.h:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <string>      
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#ifndef UNTITLED_FUNCTIONS_H
#define UNTITLED_FUNCTIONS_H

void readResponses(ifstream &infile, string responses[], string categories ,const int MAXSIZE, int &size );

#endif //UNTITLED_FUNCTIONS_H
```

functions.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <string>      
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;



void readResponses(ifstream &infile, string responses[], string 
    categories[], const int MAXSIZE, int &size ) {

    string s;
    int num = 0;
    infile.open("magic.txt");

    size = 0;
    while (getline(infile,s) && (num < MAXSIZE)) {

        responses[num] = s;
        getline(infile, s);
        categories[num] = s;
        num++;
    }
    size = num;

    infile.close();

}
```

Comment: ***I keep getting an error that says there is no matching function to call*** Please edit your question and add the exact text of the error message. If this is Visual Studio copy that from the Output tab its in a better format than the errors list.

Comment: in `main` `categories` is an array, in `readResponses` `categories` is a single string

Comment: Why are you using the `start:` label?  In most (90%+) programs, labels are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `readResponses`, You declared `string categories` and you use `string categories[]` in your definition